# terra_rasterize Error: [rasterize] cannot create dataset

Tags: terra, rasterize

I am trying to use the **rasterize** function in the **R** package **terra** (v.1.6-7) to transfer population values associated with municipalities to a raster. I am doing this for two shapefiles, `dipomun00gw.shp` and `municipiosPOP.shp`. This is the code:

```
library(terra)

# Read shapefiles for 2000 and 2010
v_00 <- vect("dipomun00gw.shp")
v_10 <- vect("municipiosPOP.shp")

# create blank rasters using each year's shape file as extent
r_00 <- rast(v_00, res=.01)  
r_10 <- rast(v_10, res=.01)  

# Rasterize
x_00 <- rasterize(v_00, r_00, "POTO00")
x_10 <- rasterize(v_10, r_10, "POB_10")  
#Error: [rasterize] cannot create dataset
```

For some reason, `v_00` rasterizes without any issues, but `v_10` produces the an error.

I cannot identify what characteristic of the shapefile `municipiosPOP.shp` is causing this error.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Shapefiles can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yS1KTGX0zLewfyL08jh8m3ZI2CPOzg2U?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `r_10` is too large (it has > 6.4e+16 cells!)

```
r_10
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 203046581, 317517559, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
#extent      : 907821.8, 4082997, 319149.1, 2349615  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
```

This is because you assigned a spatial resolution of 0.01 (that is ~1 cm), where you presumably assumed you were using 0.01 degrees (~1 km). If you first project `v_10` to long/lat (like `v_00`) your code works.

```
v_10 <- project(v_10, crs(v_00))
```